# How to iterate 'dict' with 'enumerate'

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code. This just show me one user instead of all the users I have inside my JSON, and also I have another problem, when I'm concatenating my strings it show me a "\" after I put a '"':

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    users = Caseworker.objects.all()
    response = self.serializer(users, many=True)
    for j in range(0,len(response.data)):
     dictionary = response.data[j]
     myresponse = ""


    for i, (val, v) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
         myresponse = myresponse + '{"text":' + '"' + v + '"' + '}' + ','
         print(myresponse)
    # for i,(k,v) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
    #   myresponse = myresponse + '{"text":' + '"' + v + '"' + '}' + ','
    #   print(myresponse)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'messages': myresponse}), content_type='application/json')
```

[image]

I got registered two different users

[image]

With this code I need that all my users appear in http://127.0.0.1:8000/panel/api, but instead that, everytime I add a new one, is the unique that appear in here.

In this image is the example, I added a new one and is the unique user I can visualize. [image]

Comment: Um, are you trying to manually construct a json string? It's probably much easier to manipulate python objects then `json.dumps(python_object)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need to do it manually because I'm going to integrate it with Chatfuel JSON API, and they need this estructure:

{
 "messages": [
   {"text": "Welcome to the Chatfuel Rockets!"},
   {"text": "What are you up to?"}
 ]
}

so basically that's why I'm doing it

Comment: ... so they want the values of the the `"message"` key to be a *json string* that looks like a tuple of json-objects? EDIT: nope, just as I suspect it, they want a json-array of json-objects...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand what do you mean, I'm practicing with this model that contains objects but actually it's not going to work like that. But I need to solve this problem, about why is just showing my one user instead of all and the "" problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `{'messages': myresponse}` is a *dictionary* that has a string representing JSON* as a value to `'messages'`, which is why you see the back-slash escapes behind the `"` character, because that is a *json string*, not a json-object. You should work entirely in the realm of python objects then deserialize at the end, don't mix the two, because you are getting exactly what you ask for. Instead:

```
myresponse = [{"text":v} for v in dictionary.values()]
```

*Really, that string isn't even json, but it looks like a "tuple" of JSON-objects.

To be more explicit, you are confusing the following two things, what you *want* is:

```
>>> d = {"foo":"bar"}
>>> json.dumps({"messeges":d})
'{"messeges": {"foo": "bar"}}'
```

What you are doing:

```
>>> json.dumps({"messeges":'{"foo":"bar"}'}) # notice '{"foo":"bar"}' is a string
'{"messeges": "{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"}'
```

Comment: Will you know why it doesn't show me the other users?

Comment: @PilarFigueroa  i don't know what you mean, can you provide an example? I.e., what does `dictionary` look like, what does `myresponse` look like, and what is it *suppose* to look like.

Comment: Yes, sure, I have two users registered in my DB through Django Admin, this code suppose to show me both or any other user I add in the future, but it's just showing me one.